# Receber uma String longa com um esp 01

Tags: python, c, arduino

Eu tenho um esp 01(Modulo wi-fi) ligado no meu Arduino na porta 2 e 3(TX RX), eu consigo enviar uma String grande, porem quando vou receber eu só consigo receber no máximo 32 caracteres, aqui esta o código do meu Arduino:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//TX RX
SoftwareSerial esp8266(2, 3);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    esp8266.begin(19200);
    ...
}

...


void loop() {

...

    if (esp8266.available() > 0) {

        String string = "";

        if (esp8266.find("[msg]:")) {
            string = esp8266.readStringUntil('\r');
        }

        /* Eu tentei desta forma também, mas o resultado foi o mesmo
        while (esp8266.available()) {
            string += (char) esp8266.read();
        }
        */

        Serial.print("\r\n" + string);  
    }

...
```

Estou enviando e recebendo através deste código Python as informações:

```
import socket

class socketClient(object):
    socket = None

    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.connect(((ip, port)))

    def send(self, msg):
        self.socket.send(msg)

    def close(self):
        self.socket.close()

    def receive(self):
        return self.socket.recv(10240)

status = raw_input('Entre com o estado: ')
json = '[msg]:' + status + '\r\n';
print json

#This part was to test with a local server python
#socket = socketClient('127.0.0.1', 7000)

socketClient('192.168.0.43', 80)
socket.send(json)
msg = socket.receive()
print(msg.decode('utf-8'))
socket.close()
```

Para ter certeza que o problema é no Arduino fiz uma simulação local utilizando outro código Python:

```
import socket

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 7000
addr = (host, port)
serv_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serv_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serv_socket.bind(addr)
serv_socket.listen(10)
print 'aguardando conexao'
con, cliente = serv_socket.accept()
print 'conectado'
print "aguardando mensagem"
recebe = con.recv(1024)
print "mensagem recebida: "+ recebe
serv_socket.close()
```

E recebi toda a string normalmente.

**UPDATE**

> Fiz o seguinte teste colocando o modulo diretamente nas portas TX RX e
>   enviei os comando manualmente para conectar na rede, e a string estava
>   completa(A que veio através do Python), então o problema pode ser na
>   porta 2 e 3 do Arduino que não consegue transmitir toda a informação
>   como a porta RX TX, ou a biblioteca SoftwareSerial não consegue
>   capturar toda string, ou o que eu espero que seja, para pegar toda a
>   string é necessário um método diferente.
>
> O problema maior é que eu não tenho ideia de como vou fazer qualquer
>   tipo de teste para constatar qual é o real problema.

**UPDATE**

Fiz o seguinte teste, desta forma eu envio diretamente para o `serial monitor` o que recebo do esp8266, e todos os caracteres são mostrado:

```
while (esp8266.available() > 0) {
    Serial.write(esp8266.read());
}
```

De alguma forma ao tentar passar para String ele corta a informação, pensei na possibilidade de ser o limite do objeto String, mas fiz um teste atribuindo a String diretamente e funcionou também.

Por algum motivo ao fazer a conversão para String ele acaba não pegando toda a informação.

**UPDATE**

```
String buffer = "";

void loop() {
    if (esp8266.available() > 0) {
        buffer = esp8266.readStringUntil('\r');
    }
    if(buffer != ""){
        Serial.print("\r\n" + buffer);
    }
    buffer = "";
    delay(1000);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Fiz outros testes, e conseguir fazer a atribuição da string completa em uma variável, mas o problema é o delay, mas eu não entendo o porque, pois ele esta do lado de fora do while, pensei na possibilidade de esta passando duas vezes no while e completando a string na segunda vez que ele roda, mas não é isso que acontece, para fazer este teste eu coloquei algo para ser impresso do lado de fora do while e a informação foi impressa separa da string completa, ou seja ele completou o while para depois fazer outra ação, porem quando eu coloco um delay ele não pega a string completa, o que pra mim não faz sentido algum, já que o delay esta do lado de fora do while, teoricamente não era pra fazer diferença.

```
while (esp8266.available() > 0) {
    Serial.write(esp8266.read());
}
delay(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu não trabalho com o ESP-01, só com o Esp-8266 e Esp-32,
mas se tem o limite dos 32 bytes, podes fazer o seguinte:

- Altera o Python para enviar em blocos de 32 bytes (o \n ou (\r\n) só irá no bloco final)
- E no Esp, fazes o seguinte:

  ```
  void loop() {

      // Buffer de recepção de dados

      static String bufferRecSerial = ""; // Note que é static, senão o conteúdo é perdido entre um loop e outro

      ///.....

      // Recebimento de dados

      if (esp8266.available() > 0) {

          while (esp8266.available()) {

              char caract = (char) esp8266.read();

              if (caract == '\n') { // Nova linha

                  // Processa a mensagem (agora sem o \r\n)

                  if (bufferRecSerial.length() > 0) {

                     processarMensagem(bufferRecSerial);

                     // Zera o buffer

                     bufferRecSerial = "";
                  }

              } else if (caract != '\r') { // Ignora o \r

                // Adiciona no buffer // TODO: fazer logica de timeout se necessario

                bufferRec += caract;

              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Esp-8266 é o chip, inclusive ele esta presente no esp 32, existem vários módulos com o Esp-8266 e o modelo que estou usando é o esp 01, que é o modelo mais simples https://www.filipeflop.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/WiFi-Serial-Transceiver-Module.jpg

Comment: Eu atualizei a pergunta, de alguma forma ao passar para String ele esta picando a informação, não sei se é por causa do delay na conversão.

Comment: Wictor, a plataforma é Espressif, a fornecedora de todos os chips Esp.Sim o Esp01 é um membro da família Esp8266, como o Esp-12F também. Mas o esp32 não é esp8266, e sim um upgrade deste, tem 2 cores, bluetooh, etc.

Comment: Wictor, a variável do buffer estiver no loop e não for static, isto pode acarretar a perda de dados

Comment: Como declaro uma variável static?

Comment: Para entenderes?

Variável não estática, cada vez que o Arduino executar o loop, está é criada:

void loop() {

    // Buffer de recepção de dados

    String bufferRecSerial = ""
....
} 
Variável estática (vide o static na declaração) -> indica ao compilador criar somente uma vez e manter isto na memória. ex.:

void loop() {

    // Buffer de recepção de dados

    static String bufferRecSerial = ""

}

Outra alternativa é declarar a variável como global, ou seja fora de qualquer funcão

Comment: Fiz, coloquei a variável global e também testei colocando 'static' dentro do método loop, porem o resultado foi o mesmo.

Comment: Wictor, como estás fazendo ? por favor enviar o código alterado

Comment: Editei e postei a modificação.